# Conditional observable interaction RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following observables:

```
this.searchValue$ = this.searchValue.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  debounceTime(500)
);

this.cardAmount$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
  startWith(0),
  scan(count => count + 20, 0)
);
```

To add a bit more context to the code: `searchValue$` is related to input field changes and emits the value that is changed. `cardAmount$` is related to button presses. Each time you press a button it emits a new value 20, 40, 60 and so on.

I would like "set" the value of `cardAmount$` back to 0 once `searchValue$` is emited. What is a correct RxJS way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect case for the `switchMap` operator :

```
this.cardAmount$ = this.searchValue$
.pipe(switchMap( search =>
  fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
   .pipe(
    startWith(0),
    scan(count => count + 20, 0)
)));
```

A new Observable starting from 0 will be generated on each searchValue emission.

Comment: Won't that create memory leaks since you're not closing the previous subscriptions to `cardAmount$` ?

Comment: Also, won't that unbind those subscriptions, since they won't refer to the same memory reference ?

Comment: The previous subscriptions are unsubscribed by the switchMap operator before subscribing the new Observable. Here is a stackblitz demo of that : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52988879
And the source code of the unsubscription : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/c9cbdae16d791664f11cc3f309d0ee11217b56d9/src/internal/operators/switchMap.ts#L114 . I'm not sur about what you mean by the subscriptions unbinding ?

Comment: Oh you're right, forgot that feature of switchMap ! About the "unbinding", I meant that when you write `const x = this.cardAmount$.subscribe(...)`, you subscribe to one memory reference, so if you change it to another, doesn't that "unbind" or "cancel" (sorry not a native speaker) this subscription, meaning you have to subscribe to the new memory reference again ?

Comment: (That's just out of curiosity, I'm learning RxJs myself, so have my upvote for your clean & lean code)

Comment: The  `switchMap` operator instance will keep track of the subscription reference until unsubscription.

Answer (score 2):

You can't with this code (as far as I know).

For that, you will need a proxy that acts both as an observable and an observer. Otherwise, you can't emit a value in your stream.

Try with `BehaviorSubject` :

```
this.searchValue$ = this.searchValue.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  debounceTime(500),
  tap(() => this.cardAmount.next(0)),
);

this.cardAmount$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
  startWith(0),
  switchMap(() => this.cardAmount$),
).subscribe(curr => this.cardAmount$.next(curr + 20));
```

I slightly changed the last observer because if you don't and keep your previous one, the count value won't care about the reset of the value changes. To be sure it does care, you'll have to use the current value of the observer.